# Flex 4.1 Spark List clears selectedItems property when changing dataprovider

Tags: flash, flex4, mxml

I found an issue in the Flex framework. I use Flex 4.1.
In skin class of the MySkinnableContainer, List component defined:

```
<s:List id="myList" allowMultipleSelection="true"/>
```

Then in MySkinnableContainer, I dynamically change myList.dataProvider and myList.selectedItems. But, when I am define myList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([1,2,...]), the myList.selectedIndices doesn`t clear. I catch exception when call myList.selectedItems, because myList.selectedIndices is old. 
myList.selectedIndices = [], and so on, doesnt work. Help me, please. Thank, you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Solution is, by steps:

1. First, when you set dataProvider =
   new myArrayCollection([1,2...]),
   then, you must waiting for
   updateComplete event - the
   selectedItems and selectedIndices
   now is clear.
2. Second, you can set
   your own selectedItems, ex.
   selectedItems = new Vector.int(),
   and before you call getter
   selectedItems, you must waiting for
   valueCommit event.
3. Third, now you can
   call getter selectedItems wothout
   exception.